# Does Facebook return Album date

Tags: facebook, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

When you fetch an album from Facebook, does it also return the date what you selected in the "Edit Date" field? I don't mean the created or updated date.

Answer (score 0):

No, only the creation time and updated time for the album are returned via the API, the point on a user's Timeline that the album appears (e.g. if they backdated the album) is not returned via the API